# read XML File to get only one value android

Tags: java, android

i tried to get data from xml file by URI Content provider and i success, but i want to get only one value, and this method doesn't work for me ...  also is it a good idea to use array and insert all xml values in.

```
public void requestContent() {
    try {
        Uri singleUri = Uri.parse(APP_XML_URI);
        InputStream instream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(singleUri);
        BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
        String MD5;
        try {
            while (( MD5 = reader1.readLine()) != null) {
                try
                {
                    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                    SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
                    DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler()
                    {
                        boolean MD5_PIN = false;
                        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
                        {
                            if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("MD5"))
                            {
                                MD5_PIN=true;
                            }
                        }
                        public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException
                        {
                            if (MD5_PIN)
                            {
                                String  MD5_SPIN = new String(ch, start, length);
                                appContent.append("TEST \n");
                                appContent.append(MD5_SPIN + "\n");
                                MD5_PIN = false;
                            }
                        }

                    };
                    saxParser.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(MD5)), handler);
                    //new InputSource(new StringReader(MD5))
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                appContent.append(MD5 + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details about *"this method doesn't work for me"*.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this approach looks a bit strange.

If I understand the code correctly, it is reading the input one line at a time, and creating a SAX parser to parse each line.

Assuming that the URI resolves to an ordinary XML document<sup>1</sup>, this is not going to work.  The first line will consist of a partial XML document, and the parser will (probably) fail at the end of the line.  The second line will consist of text from the middle of the XML document, and the parser will (probably) fail at the beginning ... because the "XML" it is parsing is not well-formed.

(There are other problems with the code, but I think they are due to its "proof of concept" nature ...)

So what I think you should be doing is (high level!):

1. Code a SAX parse event handler that causes the parser to terminate when it encounters the one element that you are looking for.
2. Instantiate the parser with an InputSource that reads directly from the `BufferedReader`.
3. When the parser terminates (for whatever reason) make sure that the `BufferedReader` is closed.

---

<sup>1 - The only case where this approach will work is if each line of the input "document" is a complete self-contained XML document!</sup>